# Wireless problem in Lubuntu!

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I'm trying to save my parents time by installing Lubuntu. Everything is fine apart from the  wireless. If I run `nm-applet`  I get this error

```
** (nm-applet:1850): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(nm-applet:1850): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) An agent with this ID is already registered for this user.
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.